# How to add dynamic Viewpager Height

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I have a Viewpager that displays items in a 3 x 3. This Viewpager is part of a layout with other views so it height needs to be set dynamically based on the number of items in the page.

Based on this question I have created a custom viewpager overriding the onMeasure like so:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        try {
            View child = getChildAt(mCurrentPagePosition);
            if (child != null) {
                child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                int h = child.getMeasuredHeight() * 3;
                heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int count = this.getChildCount();
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

This expanded the Viewpager to show three items in a row like this:

[image: Viewpager showing three rows]

I am looking for a way to dynamically set the height to either

```
int h = child.getMeasuredHeight() * 1;
```

or

```
int h = child.getMeasuredHeight() * 3;
```

Based on the number of items displayed in page, so I can shrink the height dynamically. Any pointer is appreciated.

[image: Viewpager showing two rows]

and

[image: Viewpager showing two rows]

Answer (score 1):

How about you call setMeasuredDimension with the desired dimensions?

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    try {
        View child = getChildAt(mCurrentPagePosition);
        if (child != null) {
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight() * 3;
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int count = this.getChildCount();
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, h);
}
```

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you, however this did not change the height of the Viewpager. It gave me some food for thought and I will continue to explore/